# what is wrong about this script?

Tags: python, numpy, integer-division

I am really confused what is exactly wrong. for first part of if the answer is always 0.0 , even separated part of formula are not 0. 
what is wrong here?

```
import numpy as np
def concpt(E,E0,theta):
    rad= theta*(np.pi/180)
    M=np.cos(rad)
    print(M)
    thrcondtion= 0.5*E*E0*(1-M)
    if thrcondtion>= 1:
        x=(1-(1/(E*E0*(1-M))))**0.5
        print(x)
        RESULT= (3/16)*(1-(x**2))* (((3-(x**4))*(np.log((1+x)/(1-x))))-(2*x*(2-(x**2))))
        print(RESULT)
        return RESULT
    else:
        print("invalid")
```

Comment: Some context information would be very helpful. Please describe what this script is supposed to do and what the expected results are. Also some example inputs would help, too.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
>>> print(3/16)
```

at a Python prompt.

It will print

```
0
```

Because the calculation is done using integers, since `3` and `16` are both integers. You need e.g. `3.0 / 16` there, to get `0.1875`.